# Q: Z3, incorrect quantifier elimination for formulas containing division of int

Tags: z3

I was trying to eliminate quantifier from a formula which contains a bit shifting of an int variable, like `\exists y. y=x>>1` for int x and y. Since there is no bit shifting operation for int in Z3, I tried 2 method to simulate bit shifting:

1) Converting int to bitvector and converting back after bit shifting. Where the code is

```
(declare-const y Int)
(assert (exists ((x Int)) (= y (bv2int (bvlshr ((_ int2bv 8) x) #x02)))))
(apply qe)
```

2) Using division and multiplication to simulate shifting. Where the code is

```
(declare-const y Int)
(assert (exists ((x Int)) (= y (div x 4))))
(apply qe)
```

But for both of methods the output still contain quantifer `exists ((x Int))`. Is this caused by bugs or I need to use some tactics to make it work. Is there any possible way to shift a int variable in quantifiers elimination